# Replace Video Resource with VIMEO API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to replace existing video on VIMEO with 
advanced api from : https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#replace-videos-from-the-server.

The code is:

```
$vimeo = new \Vimeo\Vimeo('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$vimeo->setToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$video_id_on_vimeo = 123456; // not real id
$vimeo->replace("/videos/" . $video_id_on_vimeo, $path_to_file, false);
```

However it throws me an error "Unable to get an upload ticket.[The requested user could not be found]'

All other commands do work. I am using OAUTH 2 and scopes configured for using apis are: 
public private purchased create edit delete interact upload.

in order to run example, just execute POST request to http://panels.veedi.com/api/video/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo development team fixed the bug.
Now everything is working. In addition in API description of replacement process, they have mistake.
Instead of:

```
$response = $lib->upload('/videos/12345', '/home/aaron/Downloads/ada.mp4', false);
```

You should use:

```
$response = $lib->replace('/videos/12345', '/home/aaron/Downloads/ada.mp4', false);
```